# SnackBars in flutter only shows once

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-getx, snackbar

I want to give an error warning if the input given in the text field is  not correct (like the field  only accepts integer and not characters  or strings). I have used
`Get.snackbar` for giving the error warning . but it show only once after opening the application. How to solve this issue {Thanks in advance}

Comment: You can make a minimal project to reproduce your problem and paste code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create a title for you snackbar as a string

```
String? sbTitle;
```

then you can create a function which can show snackBar every time you call it

```
void showSnackBar(BuildContext context) {
  final scaffold = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
  scaffold.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(sbTitle!),
      action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Ok', onPressed: scaffold.hideCurrentSnackBar),
    ),
  );
}
```

and finally every time you want to show and error just set the title to your error code and pass in the function like this

```
 sbTitle = "Invalid input";
 showSnackBar(context);
```

this will save you so much time cause you dont have to build snackbar every time you want to show snackbar

Answer (score 0):

I tried the SnackBar widget as a function. it worked!!!

Comment: then please remove this answer and mark the above answer as the correct answer